# What is the best way to replace a letter with the letter following it in the alphabet in Java?

Tags: java, replace, letter, alphabet

I'm a programming newbie and I am doing a coderbyte exercise that says "
Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a)"

i'm thinking of the following methods:

1. declare a string called "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz" and compare each string's char index position with the alphabet's index position, and then just bring the alphabet char that is located at the i+1 index location. But I don't know how it would work from z to a.
2. I've seen some techniques using ASCII values for every char but I've never done that before and not sure how it works
3. convert the given string into a char[] array, but then I'm not sure how I would tell the system to get me the next alphabet char

What would be the easiest way to do this?

*EDIT*
this is my code so far, but it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String LetterChanges(String str) {
    // code goes here 
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String newWord = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); i++){
        if (str[i] == alphabet[i]){
          if (alphabet[i+1].isVowel()){
          newWord = newWord + toUpperCase(alphabet[i+1]);
          }
          else{
            newWord = newWord + alphabet[i+1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return str;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LetterChanges(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

Can't I ask for the index position of a Char that is a part of a String? in C I could do that.
Other than that not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Method 1 sounds good to me. As for the z-to-a edge case, you could [%26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) the 0-based index I suppose. Or a good old `if`.

Comment: You've messed around with indices `i` and `j`. I think you've meant `alphabet[j]`, not `alphabet[i]`. Also in Java we have method [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)), it does internally what your nested `for`-loop is intended to do. But **note** that it's redundant for this task.

Comment: `.isVowel()` - seems to be an unnecessary artifact accidentally copied from somewhere else. Please, fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with method 1.

I believe what you're looking for is the `indexOf` method on a `String`.
First of, I would create a method that given a character finds the next letter in the alphabet and return that. This could be done by finding the letter in your alphabet string and then fetch the letter at index+1. As you also pointed out you would need to take care of the edge case to turn 'z' into 'a', could by done with an if-statement or by having an extra letter 'a' at the end of your alphabet string.

Now all that remains to do is create a loop that runs over all characters in the message and calls the previously made method on that character and constuct a new string with the output.

Hope this helps you figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there would be only lower case English letters in the given `String` the most performant way would be to add `+1` to every character, and use either `if`-statement checking whethe the initial character was `z` or use the [modulo operator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRx7yn0N_5AhUKl4sKHXxSCcwQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModulo_operation&usg=AOvVaw3HGWtuIdoNdD7Ahy948lWx) `%` as *@sp00m* has pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473612/what-is-the-best-way-to-replace-a-letter-with-the-letter-following-it-in-the-alp/73474568#comment129749951_73473612).

Performing a search in the alphabetic string (*option 1* in your list) is **redundant**, as well extracting array `char[]` from the given string (*option 3*).

*Checking the edge case:*

```
public static String shiftLetters(String str) {
    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char next = str.charAt(i);
        if (next == 'z') result.append('a');   // checking the edge case
        else result.append((char) (next + 1));
    }
    
    return result.toString();
}
```

*Applying modulo operator:*

```
public static String shiftLetters(String str) {
    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char next = (char) ((str.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1) % 26 + 'a');
        result.append(next);
    }
    
    return result.toString();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(shiftLetters("abc"));
    System.out.println(shiftLetters("wxyz"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
bcd   // "abc"
xyza  // "wxyz"
```